# Core Data Background Thread Returning Inserted NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, background-thread

In my app I am using a NSPersistantContainer with two NSManagedObjectContexts (viewContext & background context). All my read operations are performed on view context, while all my write operations are performed on the background context (shown below).

**Creating a new Animal class**

```
class func new(_ eid: String) {
    //Create Animal Entity
    let container = CoreDataService.persistentContainer
    container.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
        let mo = Animal(context: context)
        mo.eid = eid
        mo.lastModified = Date()
        mo.purchaseDate = Date()
        mo.uuid = UUID()

        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is I need to return the newly created NSManagedObject (**Animal**) back to the manager class, where the **Animal.new(eid)** was called, to be used to show the object properties.

I have experimented with using a completion handler, but had issues returning the value, as was using a background NSManagedObject in the main thread.

**Using possible new function**

```
Animal.new(eid) { (animal) in
if let animal = animal {

}
```

What is the best approach for returning a newly created NSManagedObject, created in a background context?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to keep my CoreData managed objects within my CoreDataManager class, not exposing them out to the rest of my framework.  So methods that are to create one or more managed objects would accept the data as an unmanaged object, and then create the managed object but not return it (as callers already have the unmanaged object).  When fetching from the CoreDataManager, I'd create and populate a unmanaged object(s) and return that.

Now part of why I do this is because I'm using CoreData in a framework, such that I'd never want to hand a managed object to a client app of my framework.  But it also solves other problems like the one you described.

(When I write apps, I use Realm, and those objects can go straight to app's UI classes because Realm is so much easier to, erm, manage. :)

Comment: Can you please show some code implementing using unManagedObject?

Comment: By unmanaged object, I just mean a class containing the same properties as a CoreData-managed object, and that has nothing to do with CoreData.  You just write code to map your CoreData-managed object's properties to a new object of such a class.

Comment: Just starts getting messy when you have to start mapping as my **Animal** object has multiple relationships.

Comment: Yep, but there are a lot of benefits, too. The rest of your codebase doesn't have to be careful to follow CoreData's rules. The objects are also easier to see in the debugger. You'd be bottlenecking any edits to your CoreData objects to within your CoreDataManager only, which also aids in debugging. Maybe there'll be a different answer here.

Comment: Also: I use Realm for my apps to avoid such problems... the schemas are much easier to define and maintain, I can avoid the need of multiple moc's and the threading mess with those.  It's tough to write concurrent CoreData correctly, where the main moc and background moc get sync'd at the proper times. With CoreData no matter how careful you are, there's always a super-rare crash or two you'll never get rid of.